Is there an image cropping interface in PhotosUI/SwiftUI
I am unable to find a way to show the cropping interface like in WhatsApp when using PhotosUI in SwiftUI.
Eg:

I’m assuming this is the standard UI provided by Apple and not custom made by WhatsApp. How do I use this interface in my SwiftUI app? Does PhotosUI or some other Apple framework provide means to use this interface in SwiftUI?
Please let me know. Thanks.

That looks like a custom UI to me

This looks like custom UI, from what I remember you can set allowsEditing on a UIImagePickerController and this allows the user to access some basic editing options.
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

/// Also make sure to grab the edited image and not the original
if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
    image = editedImage
}


As mentioned the editing is quite limited with this approach, such as being limited to a square crop iirc. If you want more customisability then a library might work better. TOCropViewController is a popular choice.
